# Creating coordinates out of elements in arrays in lists in a bigger list

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I've got a list Beam_points, which is a list of lists of 3 element arrays (e.g. `Beam_points[2] = [array([1,2,3]), array([2,3,4])]`). Each list of arrays is a list of points of a given ray in the beam. I'm trying to plot the z vs. y coordinates for each beam's path in the following way:

```
def plot(self):
    z_coords, y_coords = [], []
    for list in self.Beam_points:
        z, y = [], []
        for i in list:
            z.append(i[2]), y.append(i[1])
        z_coords.append(z), y_coords.append(y)      
    for z,y in zip(z_coords, y_coords):
            plt.plot(z, y, color = "Blue")
    plt.title('Beam Path')
    plt.xlabel('z')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()
```

Though there must be a more efficient/pythonic way of doing so? It takes a fairly long time to plot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more features of `numpy`, and use only one loop to plot:

```
def plot(self):
    ultra_beam_point = np.array(self.Beam_points)
    for z,y in ultra_beam_point[:,:,1:]:
        plt.plot(z, y, color = "Blue")
    plt.title('Beam Path')
    plt.xlabel('z')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()
```